# Why does first PYQT signal emit and subsequent signals do not?

Tags: python, arduino, pyqt, qthread

The following code is in a thread that acquires data from an Arduino Uno board. I am experiencing an issue when emitting signals to other threads. The first signal emits fine and does what it is supposed to do, however the subsequent signals do not emit. I tried rearranging the order of the signals so that ai2, or io0 emits first and it is the same. The signal that I put on top and ran first gets emitted and the other two do not. Does anyone know why?

```
class DaqThread(QtCore.QThread):
     def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(DaqThread,self).__init__(parent)
        self.exiting = False
    #define QtCore.Signal variables to emit
     ai0 =    QtCore.Signal(str)
     ai2 =    QtCore.Signal(str)
     io0 =    QtCore.Signal(str)
     #io1 =    QtCore.Signal(str)
     #io2 =    QtCore.Signal(str)
     #io3 =    QtCore.Signal(str)
     #io4 =    QtCore.Signal(str)     
     ser = serial.Serial(usbport, 115200) #setup serial


     #get Arduino state

     def arduino(self):       
        lines = self.ser.readline()

        if 'A0' in lines[0:2]:     # -Repeat for other variables   
            stlen = len(lines)      #get string length
            ach0 = (lines[3:(stlen)]) 
            f0 = float(ach0)
            ach0 = f0 / 206.4 #change to volts
            ach0 = str(ach0)

        if 'A2' in lines[0:2]:     # -Repeat for other variables   
            stlen = len(lines)      #get string length
            ach2 = (lines[3:(stlen)]) 
            f2 = float(ach2)
            ach2 = f2 / 206.4 #change to volts            


        if 'D2:' in lines[0:3]:     # -Repeat for other variables   
            stlen = len(lines)      #get string length
            io0 = (lines[3:(stlen)]) 
            io0 = str(io0)


        self.ai0.emit(ach0)
        self.ai2.emit(ach2)
        self.io0.emit(io0)
        self.ser.flush()


     def run(self):
         while 1:
             try:
                 self.arduino()
             except:
                 pass
             time.sleep(0.005)
```

Comment: what is the `str` parameter you giving in the to the Signals ? Where does it comes from ?

Comment: @Overdrivr. It's the python `str` type.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. (Hint: the arduino/serial stuff is unlikely to be relevant).

Comment: Your `except: pass` is a really bad thing to do, it hides any and all exceptions. Remove it and see if that helps you finding out what's going wrong.